# Transformation of a valid covariance matrix

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, covariance

Suppose we have a normally distributed random variable $\boldsymbol{X}$ with covariance matrix $\Sigma$, which is symmetric positive definite.

Now if I multiply $\boldsymbol{X}$ by some matrix A, the resulting random variable has covariance:

cov($A \boldsymbol{X}$) = $A\Sigma A'$.

Is there any restrictions on the matrix A such that $A\Sigma A'$ is a valid covariance, ie is symmetric positive definite with full rank and non zero determinant?

Edit:

$\Sigma$ is a diagonally dominant matrix of size 10x10, with 6 in the diagonal elements and -1's in 5 of the columns for each row.

Matrix A contains data and is large 480x10.  I have tried using just random generated normal data in A and get the same issue that $A\Sigma A'$ has rank 10 and zero determinant.  The rank of the resulting matrix seems to depend on the rank of $\Sigma$.

Comment: Any linear transform of a random variable with covariance is also a random variable. It should also have a covariance. How would it be any different?

Comment: The reason I ask is because I have tried this for a particular A and get a singular covariance matrix after the transformation.  Hence my question of if there is some restrictions on what A can be.

Comment: @darren86: If you can put your problematic $X,\Sigma,A$ into the question it might be possible to understand your problem better.  Covariance matrices can be singular, and in your example will be for example if $A$ has zero determinant or if $A$ has more rows than columns.

Comment: @Henry Question edited.  If A has more rows than columns with the resulting matrix be singular?  Is this a general result?  Do you have a link?  Thanks

Comment: How can one multiply these matrices if their dimensions (480x6 and 10x10 respectively) do not fit?

Comment: the only restriction for $\mathbf{A}$ is $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{X}$ are multipliable, if the resulting $\mathbf{A\Sigma A^T}$ is singular, it is really okay, because, similar to the one dimensional case, it is not strange to have a $\sigma^2=0$, then we can consider singular $\mathbf{A\Sigma A^T}$ as a 'zero' variance

Answer (score 1):

The condition which you need on $A$ is that it $A$ has full row rank. 
That is, we want the rows of $A$ to be linearly independent.
Assume $A$ has $d$ rows and $m$ columns.
A necessary but not sufficient condition for this to hold is
that $d$ is less than or equal to $m$. This condition fails in your
example since $d = 480$ and $m = 10$.

To see why this condition holds,
note that $x'A \Sigma A' x > 0$ for all non-zero $x$
is the condition that $A \Sigma A'$ is positive definite.
If $\Sigma$ is positive definite this condition is equivalent to the
condition that $x' A \Sigma^{1/2} (\Sigma^{1/2}) A' x > 0$ which is equivalent
to the condition that $|x'A \Sigma^{1/2}|^2 > 0$. 
The matrix $A$ has full row rank if and only if $x'A$ is not an 
$m$-dimensional vector of zeros for all 
non-zero $x$ (this is an equivalent definition of the
matrix $A$ having full row rank).